# How to get the difference between two QDateTimes in milliseconds?

Tags: qt, qt4

I wish QDateTime overrode the - operator and returned a QTimeSpan representing the difference between two QDateTimes (just like .NET's TimeSpan). Since this doesn't exist in Qt, I decided to implement it.

Unfortunately, QDateTime has no `msecsTo`-like function. What is the cleanest way to get the difference between two QDateTimes accurate to the millisecond?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would probably use `a.daysTo(b)*1000*60*60*24 + a.time().msecsTo(b.time())`. Note that you need to watch how close you can be, since you're going to overflow your data type rather quickly.

Answer (score 33):

I realize that this question is from 2010, and that Qt 4.7 didn't exist back then (it actually came out about a week after this question was originally asked--September 21 2010), but for people who are looking for how to do this now:

As of Qt 4.7, QDateTime has a "msecsTo" method. See Qt 4.8 documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#msecsTo.

```
const QDateTime dateTime1 = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
// let's say exactly 5 seconds pass here...
const QDateTime dateTime2 = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
const qint64 millisecondsDiff = dateTime1.msecsTo(dateTime2);
// millisecondsDiff is equal to 5000
```

Comment: I would include the details from the link provided as part of your answer, otherwise this is likely to be closed as a link only answer

Comment: Thanks, drneel. I've added a code sample to my answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow - There needs to be a way for community to update accepted answer because over time the answer could change due to newer versions of software, new methodologies, etc.  This should be the accepted answer for now until QT changes something in the future.  I up-voted this one.

Answer (score 4):

how about this:

```
QDateTime a = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime b = a.addMSecs( 1000 );
qDebug( "%d", a.time().msecsTo( b.time() ) );
```

[Source](http://www.qtforum.org/article/33947/difference-between-two-qdatetime-in-milliseconds.html)

Comment: But that will ignore the date part altogether.

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions are good, but if your timestamp is in a particular format then you can find the difference by below, and also you can assign that to QString.

let *start* is time on some moment in some format

```
QString start = QDateTime().currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP dd/MM/yyyy");
```

let *end* is time on some moment after *start* in some format

```
QString end = QDateTime().currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP dd/MM/yyyy");
```

So, you can find the difference by providing the format and using *msecsto* and assign them to QString(if required).

```
QString timeDiff= QString("%1").arg(QDateTime().fromString(start ,"hh:mm:ss AP dd/MM/yyyy").msecsTo(QDateTime().fromString(end ,"hh:mm:ss AP dd/MM/yyyy")));
```